# how to find locust logs and result

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, locust

I had performance test by using Amazon over SSH with master and slaves. Actidentally closed the shell which stopped locust and I couldnt reach the :8089 port to get the result, and screenshots.

Is there a way that I can get the log, .csv, or anything for getting the result of my test.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `--logfile=locust_log.log` parameter when starting both master and slave locust.

By doing this, you'll be able to view the logs in `locust_log.log` file when you accidentally close locust.

An example of the command:

`locust --host=http://127.0.0.1 -f my_locust_file.py --logfile=locust_log.log --master`